# Background should adapt to content height using JQuery on window resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The content of a div will be set dynamically. The div #background, should adapt to the height that (separate) div will have. The background also should adapt to resizing of the div when the browser is resized. So the action should happen **when the page loads**, or **when the browser is resized**.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="content">
    <p>This content will be set dynamically.
        <br>The div #background should adapt to this height.
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br>This should happen when the page loads,
        <br>or when the browser is resized.
        <br>At this moment, it only works when
        <br>the page loads.
        <br>
    </p>
    <!-- end #content -->
</div>
<!-- end #wrapper -->
```

At this moment, it only works when the page loads eventhough I added this code:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#background").css({
        height: ($("#wrapper").height() + 50) + 'px'
    });
});
```

How can I get the resizing bit working? Thanks.

[here is a jsfiddle to test this](http://jsfiddle.net/cavis/GmnHN/13/)

Comment: Do you want the background to be 100% height of the container or of the window?

Comment: The #background should adapt it's height to the #content height.

Comment: Why don't you just set background color on the #content div then?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. How do you want the window to resize? The reason why is because you have a set width, so the container won't respond to resize events.

Comment: The example is a bit too simple I'm afraid. In the real situation, the content consists of two containers who are stacking on browser resize by the bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `resize` handler is working as intended, but the issue is that `#wrapper` won't change height unless you give it height, so right now you're simply updating the `height` on `#background` to the same value each time `resize` is fired:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#background").css({
        height: ($("#wrapper").height() + 50) + 'px'
        //       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this value never changes
    });
});
```

[Here's an updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GmnHN/6/) where I've added

```
html, body, #wrapper { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: That's right, there is a problem with that. How should I get the new height?

Comment: You need to give `#wrapper` a height that isn't `auto`. If you want to use a relative value (such as `%` or `em`) then you also need to ensure that `#wrapper`'s parent has height, and so on (hence the `body, html { height: 100%; }`)

Comment: This doesn't solve it, the div #wrapper does have a calculated pixel value when i alert it. Perhaps the script should fire at an 'onchange' event on the height of the contentdiv? So when the window is resized and the div height changes, it will change the background div.

Comment: Yes, when you query `.height()` it's always going to have a pixel value. My [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GmnHN/6/) works, so maybe you're after something else?

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GmnHN/5/)

use `display: inline-block`.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#background").css('display': 'inline-block');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this only fits the content background, not the div #background

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.on()`:

```
$(window).on("resize load", function () {
    $("#background").css({
        height: ($("#wrapper").height() + 50) + 'px'
    });
});
```

does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger it on load.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#background").css({
        height: $("#wrapper").height() + 50
    });
}).trigger("resize");
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

http://jsfiddle.net/dzdH5/